# Using raw_input in python for lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to use raw_input in the python code to get user input of lists as below.

```
input_array.append(list(raw_input()));
```

User input as:

```
1 2 3 5 100
```

But the code is interpreting input as

```
[['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '5', ' ', '1', '0', '0']]
```

Try: If I use plain `input()` instead of `raw_input()`, I am facing the issue in console.

```
"SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 3, '1 2 3 4 100'))"
```

Note: I am not allowed to give the input in list format like

```
[1,2,3,5,100]
```

Could somebody please tell me how to proceed further.

Comment: That data looks to you like numbers separated by spaces, but to the computer it's just a string of characters (which happen to be decimal digits and spaces).  When you cast it to a list, Python thinks you want a list composing of every individual character in the string. What you want is to separate the string into shorter substrings, using the spaces as the word delimiter; then, turn each substring into an integer and put it in a list. That's what the answer below does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
1 2 3 5 100
[1, 2, 3, 5, 100]
```

---

```
>>> raw_input().split()
1 2 3 5 100
['1', '2', '3', '5', '100']
```

Creates a new list split by whitespace and then

```
[int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

Converts each string in this new list into an integer.

---

```
list()
```

is a function that constructs a list from an iterable such as

```
>>> list({1, 2, 3}) # constructs list from a set {1, 2, 3}
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list('123') # constructs list from a string
['1', '2', '3']
>>> list((1, 2, 3))
[1, 2, 3] # constructs list from a tuple
```

so

```
>>> list('1 2 3 5 100')
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '5', ' ', '1', '0', '0']
```

also works, the `list` function iterates through the string and appends each character to a new list. However you need to separate by spaces so the `list` function is not suitable.

`input` takes a string and converts it into an object

```
'1 2 3 5 100'
```

is not a valid python object, it is 5 numbers separated by spaces. 
To make this clear, consider typing

```
>>> 1 2 3 5 100
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

into a Python Shell. It is just invalid syntax. So `input` raises this error as well.

On an important side note:
`input` is not a safe function to use so even if your string was `'[1,2,3,5,100]'` as you mentioned you should not use `input` because harmful python code can be executed through `input`. 
If this case ever arises, use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3,5,100]')
[1, 2, 3, 5, 100]
```